# ClassInitialize doesn't get called when I run all tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

ClassInitialize used to work perfectly fine, I have 2 sections in there 2 class initializers and 2 class cleanups. One of them are always active and the other are commented out because of local testing and production. At first everything was working ok, then I switched the ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup when I went back to testing on my local machine. (Keep in mind all of this code was working fine before separately.) Now when I run all tests it just skips the ClassInitialize and Cleanup and I do have TestContext in there. If anyone has any idea why it would just skip this class I would really appreciate it.

This did happen before and then I created a new class and just copy pasted the code and it worked after that, I don't want to do that every time I switch from production to local.

Comment: You might want to tag your question with the testing framework you use.

Comment: add tags so it'll be more clear what the topic is related to

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's MsTest framework.
Make sure:

1 - the method marked with [ClassInitialize] attribute is static.

2 - the method expects a parameter of type `TestContext`.

If the framework doesn't react to the attribute, you can try using [[ModuleInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers)] attribute.

Comment: The method is static yes.

Comment: Ok, added extra info.